# Getting no value in the console trying to access a element in the DOMTree : WebScrapping

Tags: typescript, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am learning webscrapping using `TypeScript` and `CheerioCrawler`

The url I am trying to access is: https://www.ycombinator.com/companies/fiber-ai

The Code is like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { RequestQueue, CheerioCrawler } from 'crawlee';


async function scrap() {
  const requestQueue = await RequestQueue.open();
  await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: 'https://www.ycombinator.com/companies/fiber-ai' });

  const crawler = new CheerioCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    async requestHandler({ $, request, body }) {
      //console.log(body);
      const title =  $('.prose > h1').text();
      console.log({title});
    }
  });
  await crawler.run();
}

scrap();
```

The output I am getting in the console is
{ title: '' }

I don't know why I am not getting the actual value
But When I try to console.log(body) I am getting whole parse tree correct only
Help me out!!